# Inconsistent file size change while writing bytes from stream to a file

Tags: c#, stream, binarystream

I have a file with size 10124, I am adding a byte array, which has length 4 in the beginning of the file.
After that the file size should become 10128, but as I write it to file, the size decreased to 22 bytes. I don't know where is the problem

```
public void AppendAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
{
    var encryptedFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    ////argument-checking here.
    Stream header = new MemoryStream(bytes);

    var result = new MemoryStream();
    header.CopyTo(result);
    encryptedFile.CopyTo(result);

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Users\\life.monkey\\Desktop\\B\\New folder (2)\\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.docx.aef"))
    {
        writer.Write(result);
    }
}
```

How can I write bytes to the file?

Comment: Do not use `StreamWriter` to write *binary* data.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be caused by:

- using a `StreamWriter` to write binary formatted data. The name does not inthuitively suggest this, but the `StreamWriter` class is suited for writing textual data.
- passing an entire stream instead of the actual binary data. To obtain the bytes stored in a `MemoryStream`, use its convenient `ToArray()` method.

I suggest you the following code:

```
public void AppendAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
{
    var fileName = @"C:\\Users\\life.monkey\\Desktop\\B\\New folder (2)\\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.docx.aef";

    using (var encryptedFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Append)))
    using (var result = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encryptedFile.CopyTo(result);
        result.Flush(); // ensure header is entirely written.

        // write header directly, no need to put it in a memory stream
        writer.Write(bytes);
        writer.Flush(); // ensure the header is written to the result stream.
        writer.Write(result.ToArray());
        writer.Flush(); // ensure the encryptdFile is written to the result stream.
    }
}
```

The code above uses the [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which is better suited for binary data. It has a [`Write(byte[] bytes)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx149a0k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method overload that is used above to write  an entire array to the file. The code uses regular calls to the `Flush()` method that some may consider not needed, but these guarantee in general, that all the data written prior the call of  the `Flush()` method is persisted within the stream.